# Eclipse Juno xml error

Tags: java, android

I have installed Eclipse Juno for creating Android apps, but when I try to import any project, after importing the project and after trying to manipulate it, it makes another file with a .out extension.

If I have only a main activity named as "main.xml", when I try to run it, it gives me an error - something like "xml build", and it creates another XML file in the layout folder named "main.out.xml". The project does not run, but if I delete that file, restart Eclipse, and re-run the project it runs just fine.

If I edit something in XML and try to run it again, then recreates that file.  Can any one tell me how to solve this issue? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right clicking on the project, then going to "Run As" and selecting Android Device.